# How can I resize an image resource in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a script that creates an image whose height depends on the depth of a recursive tree. Precalculating the height of the image would be a pain, because I would need to run a recursive function twice. Thus, I wonder if it is possible to resize the image from inside my only recursive function. Long story short, I need to resize an image resource, is it possible? For instance, how can I make the following code work? Thanks!

```
//Create the image
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 100);

//Change the image height from 100 to 1000 pixels
imagecopyresized($image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 800, 1000, 800, 100);

//Set the header
header('Content-Type: image/png');

//Output the image
imagepng($image);

//Destroy the image
imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't run your recursive function, store that data in another datatype, then calculate what your image size should be based off of that?

Comment: It COULD be done, but I think I would have to run the recursive function twice, first to fetch and store the data (in an array, say), and then to calculate the image size. But maybe not, I'm thinking about it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost perfect, except you aren't giving it the source image to work with. You need `$source = imagecreatefrompng("someimage.png");`, and then in your `imagecopyresize` set the source image argument to `$source`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, doesn't imagecreatetruecolor() return the same type of data that imagecreatefrompng() would return?

Comment: `imagecreatetruecolor` will create your "target" image, and `imagecreatefrompng` will get your "source" image.

Comment: ic.. well, I solved my problem in a different way, but I will mark your answer as correct, as it seems to be. Thanks!